# Where are the wall studs?

Tags: studs, shelving, brackets

[image]

I'd like to put upright brackets above my sewing table, but I can't seem to locate the studs. The wall is shared with my neighbor in an apartment building. My stud finder was giving me some inconclusive/uneven reads, so I used rare earth magnets to try to locate the studs. The dots indicate where there are nail/screw heads. They are anywhere from 8-12 inches apart horizontally and about 24" apart vertically.

Does this mean there are no studs? Can I drill into what appears to be horizontal studs?

Comment: Is the wall between you and your neighbor made of concrete or brick?  The drywall may be connected to horizontal furring strips that are attached to the masonry.

Comment: @Edwin I drilled a pilot hole that went 2" in and it just seems like all drywall?? The bit just has white dust on it.

Comment: There are other material possibilities as well (such as gypsum cementitious blocks)

Comment: I think [this Q&A](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/16310/7001) is related.

Answer (score 1):

24" apart vertically means there are horizontal metal strips called RC (resilient channels) Channels. They are used in sound walls to keep sound from "traveling" through the wall.

Anchoring into the metal strips will defeat their purpose and they are not great supports.

Comment: would using drywall anchors or toggles be an option then?

Comment: When we need to hang cabinets, etc. we provide blocking between the gypsum board and the studs. We don't rely on the RC channels. However, if you screw into the studs without the blocking, you will crush the gypsum board and crack it. (The gap between the metal strip and studs is about 5/8", I think. )  if you don't put much on the shelves, (you said sewing room,) then the screws may hold if you don't over-tighten. I'd try mounting the brackets into studs and as close to the metal strips as possible for strength.